# getting error while downloading meteor ; unexpectedly download stops

Tags: curl, meteor

Unexpectedly, the download stops while downloading meteor. I have been getting this error for three days. I searched a lot on internet. Some told me restart the download. I also tried to use the `wget` command. I kept getting the same error code.

[image: Link to Screenshot]

Comment: May be you are using very slow internet connection. Did you tried with other internet connection?

Comment: i also got the same reply from another site user , so i check connection for all acivities.connection is working fine. my one friend also got the same problem